# Unable to access site over HTTPS using self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configuring IIS site to use HTTPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/405978/configuring-iis-site-to-use-https)

I am developing a REST API which I want to secure with SSL/TLS. I have implemented a large part of the API which I have tested over HTTP, however, I am now at the stage where I want to switch it over to use HTTPS.

At the moment the API is hosted on a Windows XP professional SP2 box running IIS 5.1 (development environment only) and I used the `SelfSSL.exe` tool from the [IIS 6.0 Resource Kit Tools](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671) to generate a server certificate. I then configured my API to use this certificate which all appeared to work fine as I attempted to connect to my API using HTTP and I get a `403` response saying "*... must be accessed over a secure channel...*". However, the problem is when I then attempt to access the API over HTTPS it just appears to hang!

As this is a development environment at the moment I don't have a domain name (just a static IP address) and the API is running on port `81`. Also (incase it matters) the API is the default site (I replaced it).

Any ideas why I can't connect using HTTPS?

Comment: What program are you using to connect to the server?

Comment: Fiddler just now, the actual client itself will be a mobile app. Also for clarification I have enabled the "ignore client certificates" option in IIS so the client shouldn't need a valid/recognised cert for it to work.

Comment: Care to comment on the downvote.. downvoter?

Answer (score 2):

Is port 81 HTTP or HTTPS?  You can't run both on the same port, so if you're hitting `http://192.0.2.69:81/`, getting the 403, and then trying again on `https://192.0.2.69:81/`, it's little wonder you're seeing problems.

Comment: The site is setup for HTTP (enabled the *requires SSL* option). I was just verifying that it was setup for SSL only by attempting to access it via HTTP, the 403 confirms that does it not?

Comment: The 403 confirms that it wants to be accessed via HTTPS, sure, but you said in your question "when I attempt to access the same resource over HTTPS it just appears to hang!", which is what I thought you wanted help with.  Perhaps you need to understand your problem better before you ask other people to help you with it?

Comment: are you sure you just didn't misread my question? I understand my problem which is why I have posted a question.... I am trying to secure an API using TLS with a self signed certificate but when I attempt to access it via HTTPS it hangs.. I was merely giving some background information of what I have already *tried*.

Comment: @James What he's asking is whether you're trying to use :81 for both HTTP and HTTPS, which can't be done.  Getting a 403 when you try to connect with HTTP means that the server is speaking HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: @DerfK My question clearly state *I am now at the stage where I want to switch it over to use HTTPS*, I understand you can't do both on the same port. It's not just any `403` response, it specifically tells me `The page must be viewed over a secure channel` which I assumed meant it was only running HTTPS? Like I said in my question, I have generated a self-signed cert, configured my API to use it (enabled `Requires secure channel` option in IIS) but whenever I try to access any URL via HTTPS it just appears to hang.

Comment: You would not get a 403 response if you attempted to access a HTTPS port using HTTP.  You would get an SSL handshake error.

Comment: @womble you mentioned in a previous comment "*The 403 confirms that it wants to be accessed via HTTPS, sure*" now your saying it shouldn't have got a 403 to start with? How can I ensure that port 81 is DEFINITELY configured for SSL only then? I thought all I had to do was secure the site in IIS that is running on that port? I have a sneaky suspicion that port 443 is possibly not open on the router which would explain the timing out.

Comment: Yes, I said "it *wants* to be accessed via HTTPS" -- because the protocol by which the page was accessed was HTTP.

Comment: @womble yeah so what I am asking is does that not mean that it has been configured to use HTTPS only? I think I have been getting confused between the site being accessed over port 81 over HTTP and how I then go about accessing the site using HTTPS. So from the beginning.... if I have a site that is hosted as `http://127.0.0.1:81` and I want to then switch that site to using HTTPS, how would I go about it?

Comment: Do you want port 81 to accept HTTPS requests (meaning that any attempt to access it using HTTP will *not* fail with a 403, but will instead misbehave in a practically identical manner to what you're seeing now), or do you want port 81 to continue to accept HTTP requests, and have a separate port accept HTTPS requests?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4025/discussion-between-james-and-womble)

Comment: Let's not.  I loathe the idiotic web interface of SE chat.

Comment: @womble haha ok, it's basically the same interface (practically) as sitting here commenting. Anyway, to answer your question I want to swap out HTTP for HTTPS completely so the unexpected behaviour for now would be ok. Ideally I would want to re-direct any requests to HTTP to HTTPS but that's another days fire.

Comment: What you now have is a service that *must* be accessed by HTTPS. But only provides a port that speaks HTTP. So when you try to access that port using HTTP, it tells you that the *service* must be accessed using HTTPS. But when you try to access that port using HTTPS, it hangs because that port is not configured for HTTPS. The 403 is, in this case, a configuration error telling you that an HTTP port is rigged to a service that cannot be accessed using HTTP.

Comment: Ok so it's basically not possible to configure a site which is hosted on a different port to use SSL? I tried accessing the site as HTTPS without the port 81 and it just keeps giving me 404s. I have followed various tutorials which say I have done it the right way but no matter what I do I can't get access over HTTPS.

Comment: Given the fact that people have managed to run HTTPS websites on IIS, I'm inclined to think you're probably doing something wrong.  Given the length and topic drift of this question, you might want to ask a new one along the lines of "how do I configure an HTTPS vhost in IIS?" detailing what you have done, so someone who knows IIS can help you fix it.

Comment: @womble I don't doubt I am doing something* wrong, I am trying to figure out exactly what it is I *am* doing wrong. The only thing different to the tutorials I have been doing is my site is configured on port 81 instead of port 80. To be honest I don't understand why the question has drifted as I think it's pretty clear, however, perhaps I wasn't as direct as I should have been in hindsight. I will post another question, thanks.