# Configuring IIS site to use HTTPS

Tags: ssl, windows-xp, https, iis

I am working on a REST API which I have currently deployed on a Win XP Professional SP2 development machine running IIS 5.1. The site is currently being hosted on port 81 and being accessed via HTTP. I would now like to configure the site to stop using HTTP and use HTTPS only.

I have developed a self-signed certificate using the `SelfSSL.exe` tool from the [6.0 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17275) and set the `Common Name` to be the IP of my server (as it's a local development machine it has no domain name). I have also already configured the site to use SSL using the [How To Set Up an HTTPS Service in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=324069) tutorial as my guide.

However, whenever I try to access a resource in the API via HTTPS I get a 404.

Any ideas?

**Binding Configuration**

[image: IIS Bindings]

**SSL Configuration**

[image: SSL Configuration]

**Fiddler Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 10 Jul 2012 14:06:35 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_auth_pam/1.1.1 DAV/1.0.3 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
Set-Cookie: iomega=194.205.46.74.58091341929195981; path=/
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

14 
404 - Page Not Found
0
```

Comment: That version of IIS is nearly 11 years old by the way, just wanted you to know...eleven

Comment: @Chopper3 You can only work with the tools your given, the question already states it's a *development* environment.

Comment: 3 things wrong with this question: 1. what Chopper said - why even develop on an old OS/platform? Are you going to deploy the code to a IIS 7.5 in a prod environment? That doesn't make much sense 2. How is anyone supposed to troubleshoot your code if you don't post it? 3. You don't state any troubleshooting you've already tried. Are you just at a total loss? You say your API doesn't work over HTTPS, but does it work over HTTP? Can you get a "hello world" page to work over HTTPS not using the API?

Comment: @August "*why even develop on an old OS/platform*" The machine I have for development is not by choice I have been lumbered with it. "*How is anyone supposed to troubleshoot your code*" what *code* exactly do you want me to post? From what I can tell this is an IIS **configuration** issue, not a programming issue (although I could be wrong). "*you say your API doesn't work over HTTPS, but does it work over HTTP?*" I am beginning to think you didn't even bother to read the question..."*Can you get a "hello world" page to work over HTTPS*" - it's a REST API, no views are involved.

Comment: @August Also, what does it matter which version of IIS I am using? If I can resolve the issue in an old version like 5.1 I am pretty sure the skills are transferable to newer versions. I am familiar with IIS 6.0/IIS 7.5, what I am not familiar with is setting HTTPS and that's the reason I am asking the question. I understand the IIS version is important for the actual solution, however, the question shouldn't be critiqued based on this fact.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 response, then it must be working and you've got something about the site or requested URL pointing to nowhere. How exactly did you configure HTTPS? Does your application execute conditionally based on the requested URL?

Comment: @ChrisS The site is an MVC 4 WebAPI site, there are some custom routing however nothing dependent on the actual host. The site was hosting on port 81 over HTTP so for example I would access a resource like *http://127.0.0.1:81/users*. After configuring the site for SSL (see the tutorial linked in the question for how it's been configured) I then tried to access the same resource via *http://127.0.0.1/users* and I get a 404

Comment: Sorry on the mobile cant format those urls, first one is HTTP and the other is HTTPS. The port for SSL is the default 443.

Comment: What does your binding configuration look like?  Can you verify in the IIS logs that the requests are being sent to the right site?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I have updated my question with the site bindings/ssl configuration. This is the only site I have in IIS (you can't create multiple sites through IIS manager with XP, only server editions) so I would assume it would be going to this one? I did check the logs anyway, however, it doesn't really tell you what site it's going to, just gives you the verb i.e. `GET`/`POST` etc, IP (which I assume is the client IP), the URL and the status code.

Comment: @James Does this similar post help at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703090/mvc-4-web-api-iis7-5-http-404-page-not-found

Comment: @BrentPabst - Thanks for your reply, however, I don't think this is related as I can access the API over HTTP with SSL off. It's only when I try to access it via HTTPS with SSL on it doesn't work. I will try the accepted solution anyway, you never know!

Comment: @James Yea, not sure it's your verbs.  Are you getting an IIS 404 or an ASP.NET 404? There is a difference!

Comment: @BrentPabst how would I be able to tell the difference between an IIS 404/ASP.NET 404?

Comment: The ASP.NET 404 is almost like a YSOD as opposed to an IIS 404 where it simply returns a 404 and the browser displays it like normal.  The ASP.NET version doesn't actually say 404 on the HTML returned, rather "the resource could not be found" or something like that.  You may have to inspect the response using the IE dev tools or Fiddler.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the response I get from fiddler. Doesn't make sense right away, the server isn't an Apache Server :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

Based on your Fiddler it looks like you might actually have an Apache box listening on port 443.  It can be easy to overlook, especially if it was bundled with another piece of software.  Run the following command, see if port 443 is being listened to and what program is listening on it.  This should help us figure out if IIS is indeed controlling that port of if some other program is.

> netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:443

Comment: There does indeed seem to be something else listening on that port as I got `TCP MachineName:https MachineName:0 LISTENING` in the list. I noticed that `TeamViewer` was running on the server which I think by default listens on port 80 & 443. I disabled that though and still got the same problem. Not really sure what else could be listening on there.

Comment: @James Run the updated command above.  The last column should be the Process ID (PID), cross reference that with task manager to find the program running it.

Comment: Brilliant never knew you could do that :) It's IIS (inetinfo.exe) so not quite sure where the Apache server is coming from. The only thing I can think of is there is perhaps some port forwarding going on at the router. This would actually make sense of the 404s. I don't have access to the router but I have sent this onto the sys admin.

Comment: Yea something with your routing is acting up.  If you are on the local machine and navigate to "https:// localhost/myapi" do you still get the 404?  If not then you have some routing issues.

Comment: I just installed Fiddler on the server (not sure why I didn't do that to start with :S) and ran the same command via HTTPS and it worked! (weirdly though the response wasn't encrypted in fiddler and I haven't enabled the `decrypt HTTPS` option). However, I think it proves that it is definitely an issue at the router. The request is never reaching the server it must be getting routed elsewhere. Thanks for your help mate

Comment: No problem... now start a fund to get a decent dev server!

Comment: Haha couldn't agree more!! I am just glad that I wasn't going insane and I in fact **did** configure the site correctly for SSL after all :)

Comment: @James Btw, not sure if it runs on XP but installing IIS Express might be a better option on your dev box, at least gets you a sudo IIS7.5 environment.

Comment: Good shout I use IISExpress when debugging sites in VS. Will have a look and see if it's compatible with XP.

Comment: Turns out it was a mixture of a couple of things. Port 443 was indeed being forwarded to a UPnP server and the firewall on the actual server was blocking port 443. Sorted now :)